# IntelliJ generates java test class in non-standard location

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot app using maven as the build tool and I'm working from within IntelliJ IDEA. When I have IntelliJ generate a test from an existing class (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>), IntelliJ puts that test class into the corresponding package under directory *src/test*, followed by the package name, rather than the [maven standard](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) *src/test/java*.

The source class from which I’m asking IntelliJ to generate a test class is under *src/main/java*, the standard maven source directory. So I would expect the generated test to end up by default under the corresponding *src/test/java* location, since that’s the standard maven test directory.

It seems strange to me that IntelliJ would put tests directly under *src/test* rather than the standard *src/test/java*. Is there some setting in IntelliJ to specify where the generated classes go?

Comment: why do you think this is "wrong"?

Comment: Is there any reason to have the test classes in main/java instead of test/java. Typically you wont ship test classes with the final product.

Comment: src/test/java is the standard test directory location for maven projects (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: It is weird, shouldn't be happening. Do you see the `java` folder under `src/test`?

Comment: Nope, no /java directory gets created there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some tests and it seems the problem arises when you don't already have that test directory location, *src/test/java*, in your project layout.

If you don't have it already you can create it via the IntelliJ Project Structure panel (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S</kbd>, then click *Modules*).

I do notice that if you open an existing maven project into IntelliJ (File > Open) that already has that standard test library directory in its layout structure, IntelliJ does actually seem to know to put its generated test classes into that directory.